# How To restrict ftp user in /var/www/html folder only not to others directory

Tags: linux, ftp, sftp, centos6.4

Hope you all are doing fine.

Team I want to strict ftp user only for /var/www/html directory not to other's. Please share your valuable suggestion for that. I have checked lots of Blogs, Forums etc but not succeeded. I can create ftp user but user can go in any directory excluding root .. Please give me answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's called a chroot where you change the root of a filesystem for a specific user. Here's a great howto from unix.stackexchange.com

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/94603/limit-ftp-access-only-to-the-var-www-with-vsftpd

Comment: Thanks Jbrahy.... 
I am doing on it once done let you know

Comment: What's the downvote for? He asked a valid question and got an answer.

Answer (score 2):

To restrict a FTP user to a specific directory:

1. Create a new user with home directory set to the desired directory:
   sudo useradd -d /var/www/html -s /sbin/nologin ftpuser
2. Set ownership and permissions of the directory:
   sudo chown -R ftpuser:ftpuser /var/www/html
   sudo chmod -R 755 /var/www/html
3. Configure FTP server to use the new user and directory, specific steps vary by server software. For example:
   vsftpd
   Hope this will help!